# Change font size in table style

Tags: microsoft-word

I have two same custom style `StyleSM` tables. I decided to increase text font in these tables. I have edited style by increasing font size to 18.

[image]

Style was changed, but this not affected my tables in document. Why?

If I do the same with `Fill color` it applies color to StyleSM and all tables in my document.
[image]

That was expected, but why this not happens with fonts.

Comment: Tables are not a style. They can have a style but are not a style.  Try assigning StyleSM to the table.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely the case, that you've overwritten the font size within the tables by manually selecting the table / it's content and applying a new font size through the "Font" section in the "Home" tab. As soon as you do that, any font change that you are making in the table style won't have an effect anymore, since your manual overwriting has priority.

To get rid of the manual overwriting again, select the whole table and then in the "Font" section within the "Home" tab, click on the "Clear all Formatting" button.

[image]

Like this, the manual font change will be removed and the table style can do it's work again.

P.S.: I've noticed that you asked quite a few questions in the past days but you are not responding, commenting or closing these questions. When a question of yours has been properly answered and you don't need any help on it anymore, then please mark the correct answer. If your questions hasn't been answered, then leave comments so that we can help you. Otherwise, the question will stay open unnecessarilily.